# Invalid action class configuration that references an unknown class named

Tags: spring, maven, struts

Tengo  una aplicación en Struts2 y Spring con Maven, pero al tratar de realizar una acción sale el siguiente error:

> ```
> Invalid action class configuration that references an unknown class named
> ```

Excepción:

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid action class configuration that references an unknown class named [ThemeAction]
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionsServiceImpl.determineResultPath(ConventionsServiceImpl.java:99)
> ```

Esta es la configuración del **Struts** en el **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.strutsframework-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>   
    <version>${org.strutsframework-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${org.strutsframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

De esta forma llamo una acción de **Struts**

```
<action name="actionName" method="execute" class="ClassAction">
    <result name="success">/pages/fileName.jsp</result>    
</action>
```

y de esta forma declaro la acción en el **Spring.xml**

```
<bean class="com.test.action.ClassAction" id="ClassAction">
    <property name="classService" ref="classService"/>
</bean>
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error?

Answer (score 0):

Para que funcione la inyección de dependencias de Spring es necesario incluir en el descriptor de despliegue, web.xml, el listener ContextLoaderListener encargado de cargar el contexto de Spring y por tanto que Struts2 pueda utilizar la instancia  ClassAction como bean para gestionar la petición.